# Including and excluding files server side or with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way of including and excluding a file from a project rather than trying to do it in javascript?

I tried to do it with javascript but passing the absolute path in does not work.

How can I remove this file so that the path is 'dynamic' in all environments?

```
 public JsonResult MapPath()
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Site.css");
        return Json(new
        {
            Path = path

        });
    }
```

Javascript

```
 renderLoginPage = function (data) {
    path = data.Path;
    removeCSS(path);

 function removeCSS(href) {
    var sSheet = $('link[href="' + href + '"]');
    if (sSheet.length) {
        $('link[href="' + href + '"]')[0].disabled = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your needings here, what you are seeking for is a way to activate / deactivate a specific css in your project. I assume that under determinate circumstances, probably derived from user interaction.

This is not a good option. Keep in mind that, even if you manage to add or remove a link to a css stylesheet or to a javascript file from the DOM, the page should reload to allow changes to commit.

It's always a better option to activate or deactivate your styles through CSS classes. To do this you just define different styles associated to "activated" and "deactivated" classes.

When the situation that requires a change in your styles fires, you only need to change affected elements class attribute, fair easy to do from javascript, almost trivial if you use jQuery and can make use of .addClass() .removeClass() methods.

Keep in mind, also, that any element on the page can have several class names, so you can fine tune at every time which styles are active an which aren't just changing the decoration on class attributes.